# Seleccion de texto especifico de un campo

Tags: sql-server

Hace poco creé una tabla en `SQL Server`, dentro de esos datos quiero seleccionar por `descripcion` los que tengan la palabra `Ropa` y que me los muestre, así que use el comando `SUBSTRING` junto a `CHARINDEX` para obtener mis resultados específicos, quedando la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
                Descripcion,
                (CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion)+12),
                (CHARINDEX('''.',descripcion))-(CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion)+12)
            ) AS Usuario,
        *
FROM LogData
WHERE
    CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion) > 0;
```

Este me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Usuario|id|fechahora|descripcion|

edejesus|1| 2017-03-03 17:06:09.880000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

edejesus|2| 2017-03-03 17:16:13.600000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

xptdacorazon|3| 2017-03-03 17:18:15.180000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xptdacorazon'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.115.57]

edejesus|4| 2017-03-03 17:31:58.450000|Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

xcpdvtdadulqueb|5|  2017-03-03 17:35:30.790000|Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xcpdvtdadulqueb'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.242.25]
```

Como se ve en la consulta le digo que me seleccione en especial las palabras que estén después de las 12 letras que conforman `GRUPOSABANS\` incluyendo la `\`, me  lo impriman en un alias de nombre `Usuario` ademas de que haga la resta dentro de las `''` y antes de terminar en el `.`:

> **`(CHARINDEX('''.',descripcion))-(CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion)+12)`**

Y que después sean mayor a 0, y como resultado me debe de dar el nombre de usuario, que pasa de ser `GRUPOSABANS\eduardoxt` a solo ser `eduardoxt`, como ven el resultado es exitoso.

Pero ahora tengo un problema cuando quiero solo mostrar la ip, ocupo la misma consulta solo que el charindex lo agarre después de `CLIENT:` el código me quedo así:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
            Descripcion,
            (CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:',descripcion)+9),
            (CHARINDEX(']',descripcion))-(CHARINDEX('CLIENT:',descripcion)+9)
        ) AS Cliente,
    *
FROM LogData
WHERE
    CHARINDEX('[CLIENT: ',descripcion) > 0;
```

Al ejecutar la consulta me muestra en pocos segundos el resultado, pero luego me aparece este error:

> `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Ya he tratado de componerlo pero no lo logro que me muestre los resultados, mas que nada en cuestión de milisegundos muestra el resultado que quiero, pero luego me muestra el error mencionado arriba, quisiera saber que estoy poniendo mal :(.

De antemano les agradecería su ayuda :).

---------------------Actualización-----------------------------------------

Ya lo he logrado pero no logro quitar el `]` que esta al final.
El codigo que hice fue el siguiente:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
            Descripcion,
            (CHARINDEX('[CLIENT: ',descripcion)+9),
            (CHARINDEX(']',descripcion))+(CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:',descripcion)+9)
        )AS Cliente,
        len(descripcion),
    *
FROM LogData
WHERE
    CHARINDEX('[CLIENT: ',descripcion) > 0;
```

El resultado es:

```
Cliente|id|fechahora|descripcion|

10.248.56.69]|1| 2017-03-03 17:06:09.880000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

10.248.56.69]|2| 2017-03-03 17:16:13.600000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

10.248.115.57]|3| 2017-03-03 17:18:15.180000| Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xptdacorazon'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.115.57]

10.248.56.69]|4| 2017-03-03 17:31:58.450000|Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]

10.248.242.25]|5|  2017-03-03 17:35:30.790000|Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xcpdvtdadulqueb'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.242.25]
```

Como le quito ese `]` me muestra al final de la primera columna de nombre Cliente que de `10.248.242.25]` quede `10.248.242.25`.

De antemano les agredeceria la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor en el primer párrafo de la pregunta explicar exactamente lo que quieres hacer? Es que empiezas a explicar pero luego te lías con el código y no se entiende nada. ¿Quieres seleccionar sólo parte del contenido de las columnas o quieres hacer más cosas?

Comment: Solo quiero seleccionar el contenido de las columnas

Comment: Si haces uso de un `RELACE` desde un inicio creo que podría ser una solución

Comment: `RELACE` o `REPLACE` ?

Comment: Si era `REPLACE` si me sirvio.

Comment: Oh sí, disculpa, me refería al `REPLACE` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Santiago, no hay mucha ciencia en esto, a menos que puedas implementar algún CLR que ofrezca alguna funcionalidad de expresiones regulares, las herramientas básicas son bastante limitadas. Lo importante como menciona Lamak es ser paranoico con el formato de lo que vas a procesar por que es muy fácil luego que un `CHARINDEX` te de 0 por que no encuentra algo y adiós la lógica. En mi caso voy a usar una aproximación un poco distinta que la tendrás que validar vos.

En primer lugar verifico que las cadenas procesadas tengan un formato similar al que has indicado en los ejemplos mediante el `PATINDEX`, esto para evitar algún error posterior, tal vez tengas que hacerla un poco menos precisa. Luego para el usuario uso como ancla la barra `\` de esta forma no necesito ver el dominio (por si eventualmente tuvieras distinto dominios) y como ancla final el `.`. Para la IP las anclas van a ser `[CLIENTE:` y `]`. Importante cuando ubicas el ancla inicial + su longitud + 1 te va a dar la posición "desde" a recortar, la posición del ancla final la tienes que restar a la posición anterior para llegar a la longitud de recorte.

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE (
        ID INT IDENTITY,
        DESCRIPCION  VARCHAR(255)
        )

INSERT INTO @TMP (DESCRIPCION)
VALUES
('Login failed for user ''GRUPOSABANS\edejesus''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]'),
('Login failed for user ''GRUPOSABANS\edejesus''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]'),
('Login failed for user ''GRUPOSABANS\xptdacorazon''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.115.57]'),
('Login failed for user ''GRUPOSABANS\edejesus''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]'),
('Login failed for user ''GRUPOSABANS\xcpdvtdadulqueb''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.242.25]')


SELECT  DESCRIPCION,
    SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, LEN(DESCRIPCION)))-2),
            CHARINDEX('\',SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, LEN(DESCRIPCION)))-2)) + 1,
            LEN(SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, 24, LEN(DESCRIPCION)))-2))
        ) AS 'Usuario',

    SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:', DESCRIPCION) + 10,  CHARINDEX(']', DESCRIPCION) - (CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:', DESCRIPCION) + 10) )
        AS 'IP'


    FROM @TMP
    WHERE   PATINDEX ( 'Login failed for user%[\]%. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [[]CLIENT: %]' , DESCRIPCION )  <>  0
```

La salida sería algo así:

```
DESCRIPCION                                                                                                                             Usuario         IP
======================================================================================================================================= =============== ============
Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]         edejesus        0.248.56.69
Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]         edejesus        0.248.56.69
Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xptdacorazon'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.115.57]    xptdacorazon    0.248.115.57
Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\edejesus'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]         edejesus        0.248.56.69
Login failed for user 'GRUPOSABANS\xcpdvtdadulqueb'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.242.25] xcpdvtdadulqueb 0.248.242.25
```

Comment: Oh wow tu codigo es maravilloso, gracias ya probé y esta genial te lo agrdrzco es que soy nuevo el SQL Server estoy acostumbrado más a MySQL jejeje pero gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, tu código debería asegurarse de que la descripción del error contiene tanto el string `GRUPOSABANS\` como el string `[CLIENT:` antes de usar `SUBSTRING`, ya que en caso contrario te lanzará un error como el que estás obteniendo ahora (en el `WHERE` actual sólo se fija que exista `[CLIENT:`).

En ese caso, el código que yo usaría es:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN descripcion LIKE '%GRUPOSABANS%'
            THEN SUBSTRING(descripcion,
                                CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion)+12,
                                CHARINDEX('. Reason',descripcion) - CHARINDEX('GRUPOSABANS\',descripcion)
                                 - 13)
            ELSE '0' 
        END Usuario,
        CASE 
            WHEN descripcion LIKE '%[[]CLIENT:%'
            THEN SUBSTRING(descripcion,
                                CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:',descripcion)+9,
                                CHARINDEX(']',descripcion) - CHARINDEX('[CLIENT:',descripcion)
                                 - 9) 
            ELSE '0' 
        END IP
FROM dbo.LogData;
```

Comment: Ya use tu código y ya lo trate de modificar pero me sigue dando el mismo erro :(